# How do I create Java class object and run its functions in PHP?

Tags: java, php, json, class, object

I have two files, index.php and foo.java. In foo.java I have the class bar with the function foobar.

Now I want to create object baz in my index.php of the class bar and make it run function foobar. I know PHP and Java don't speak the same language, but I can use JSON to create an java object and have it call the function? If so, how?

Comment: Why vote down and not leave a comment? Please help me improve the question instead.

Comment: You can use exec() or shell_exec() commands and run java from CLI. This may be a possible way.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

pretty question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shell_exec` and run java from CLI.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('java [MyPackage.]MyClass MY_METHOD');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: You will need to return json output here. Are you getting output here?